# Scheduling more than one pendingIntent to same activity using AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-calendar, android-pendingintent

Recently I noticed strange behaviour when i tried to schedule Activities to be run in the future using AlarmManager. Look at the code below, the first activity is started in 20 seconds, while the second activity is not started in 40 seconds instead it is started only after 60 seconds. Can anyone explain why the second intent doesn't schedule the second activity to be called instead the third intent does. Does this mean that i can have only one intent for an activity in the AlarmManager.

```
//pending intent for morning
    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent1, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    //calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH + 1, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, morningTime, 0, 0);
    calendar1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar1.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);

    //pending intent for noon
    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent2, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    //calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH + 1, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, noonTime, 0, 0);
    calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar2.add(Calendar.SECOND, 40);
    alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);

    //pending intent for night
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH + 1, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, nightTime, 0, 0);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does this mean that i can have only one intent for an activity in the AlarmManager.

No, but it means that you need distinct `PendingIntents`. You are calling:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

twice, and therefore the two `getActivity()` calls are returning the same `PendingIntent`.

Either:

- Use a different value for the 2nd parameter to `getActivity()`, or
- Do something to the `Intent` objects to make them sufficiently different, such as using different action strings (note: extras are not sufficient)

Comment: thanks. this means i cannot have two identical intents scheduled to be started at different times by alarmmanager?

Comment: @JehoshaphAkshay: My first bullet gives you that. My second bullet gives you two *equivalent* `Intent`s, in that the `Intent` objects will have different contents (different action strings) but in a way that should not affect how you are using them.