# How to Pass data from One activity to another without using intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am already using a pending intent..So if I use another intent and start that intent it goes to a new activity..I want to avoid that..So without using intents I want to pass data from one activity to another possible?

Comment: What is your intention ?

Comment: I want to pass a data without using intents...already using pending intent using alarm service..so cant use another intent in the same activity...to pass data....

Comment: I think, this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561419/scheduling-more-than-one-pendingintent-to-same-activity-using-alarmmanager

Comment: thank u..I think this will help in future...but looking for other option...

Comment: How 'bout just making the variables you wanna share `static`? I'm not sure you can pass values around without using the `Parcelable` interface, which would still need to be put into the extras of an intent.

Comment: Yes,that is the problem...anyother way to send data to other activity without using intents

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use static Method to get data from one activity to another activity.Below is sample code

**First Activity**

```
public class First extends Activity {

 static First INSTANCE;
 String data="FirstActivity"; 

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    INSTANCE=this; 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }

 public static First getActivityInstance()
   {
     return INSTANCE;
   }

 public String getData()
   {
     return this.data;
   }
 }
```

**Second Activity:**

```
 public class Second extends Activity {

 String data; 

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    data=First.getActivityInstance().getData();  
    Toast.makeText(Second.this,"Data from first activity is"+data, 1).show();
   }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: great answer!! thumbs up :D

Comment: Static activities are highly discouraged due to the Android Activity lifecycle. `Intent` *is* the way to go, it is how Android is designed. Learn how to use intents right rather than trying to work against the basic concept of Android, or you will always encounter problems along the way. I know it sucks to make classes implement `Parcelable`, but that's Java, an outdated language that should have been abolished a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can try by using Singleton

```
 public class Singleton{
       private static Singleton instance;

       private Singleton(){

       }

       public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
  // your fields, getter and setter here

 }
```

Then in your 1st activity

```
Singleton a = Singleton.getInstance();
a.setFoo("something here");
```

and then your 2nd activity

```
Singleton b = Singleton.getInstance();
b.getFoo();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about set up a Global Variable Class and then set it in Activity1 and access it in Activity2 as shown below:

Global variable class file: Global.java

```
package <your packagename>;
public class Global {   
    public static String    stringToPass = "";
}
```

Set the Global variable in file: Activity1.java

```
Global.stringToPass = "your string value to pass";
    startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
```

Read the Global variable in file: Activity2.java

```
String gotString = "Global.stringToPass;
```

Beware of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the global class Application to share the datas you want to send! Just to set the datas before using them!