# how to pass data to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I used

`Intent intent = new Intent(thisactivity.this,nextactivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                 b.putStringArrayList("eventlist",event);
                startActivity(intent);`

to pass data to the nextactivity, but I don't want to jump to the nextactivity, just pass data, Is there any way to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515842/how-to-pass-data-from-one-activity-to-another-without-using-intents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass data from One activity to another without using intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515842/how-to-pass-data-from-one-activity-to-another-without-using-intents)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisactivity.this,nextactivity.class);
intent.puExtra("something", "anything");
startActivity(intent);
```

In NextActivity do this:

```
// in on create
// get like this the passed value

String comingdata = getIntent().getStringExtra("something");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisactivity.this,nextactivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("eventlist", event);
startActivity(intent);
```

For Receiving side

```
getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("eventlist");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not want to start the other activity i suppose you should not use intents. you can save the data as `public static variable` and access it in another activity, or you can save it in `shared preferences` or `database` and access them in the other activity when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity i have declared a string

`String str="abc";` // in activity1.java

and in the second activity am accessing it using this piece of code

`String str2=activity1.str;` // in activity2.java