# How to send data between activites without opening a new window

Tags: java, android

I want to send objects to an activity without opening a new window. If i've understood this right, then `StartActivityForResult` requires the activity to open. But how do i send data to another activity without opening it?

Comment: try using an eventBus , I use https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Pass data from One activity to another without using intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515842/how-to-pass-data-from-one-activity-to-another-without-using-intents)